# XCode Mac catalyst XCFramework archiving and upoading error: Code signing "A" failed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mac-catalyst

it looks like impossible for me archiving and uploading an app (previously iOS) to app store ad a mac catalyst app.

The problem is this app uses a framework, XCFramework format, compiled both for iOS, simulators, and maccatalyst. iOS upload has no problems. macOS upload has this error:

Code signing "A" failed

and digging in the logs:
"code object is not signed at all"

```
XcodeDistPipeline.~~~o9FYy8/entitlements~~~NynJeN' '--preserve-metadata=identifier,flags,runtime' '/var/folders/52/c95qs7cj1bj7svn9dnn3sr7w0000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.~~~o9FYy8/Root/Applications/VisualNoteApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/VisualnoteIosBle.framework/Versions/A'
2021-05-18 12:30:18 +0000  /var/folders/52/c95qs7cj1bj7svn9dnn3sr7w0000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.~~~o9FYy8/Root/Applications/VisualNoteApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/VisualnoteIosBle.framework/Versions/A: replacing existing signature
2021-05-18 12:30:18 +0000  /var/folders/52/c95qs7cj1bj7svn9dnn3sr7w0000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.~~~o9FYy8/Root/Applications/VisualNoteApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/VisualnoteIosBle.framework/Versions/A: code object is not signed at all
2021-05-18 12:30:18 +0000  /usr/bin/codesign exited with 1
```

"VisualnoteIosBle"is my framework

I saw some discussion on this online and tried:

- disabling bitcode on both the framework and the app
- compiling for maccatalyst only
- stripping bitcode with xcrun bitcode_strip (I get a "bundle format is ambiguous (could be app or framework)" after this)
- including directly my source in the app (I get a lot of other errors in the objective C and swift bridge)

the framework is distributed via cocoapods but including it directly give the same error

what am I possibly doing wrong? why so difficult to compile a simple framework?

I'm running out of option here ...